# Is There A Library That Converts Any String Into A Valid Class Name That Is Compliant To Code Conventions

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

For some code generation I look for a library that can convert any String to a java code convention compliant class name. E.g.

`2some_File_name` should be converted to `SomeFileName`

I want to use the converted String in a template engine to generate java classes.

This sounds like a general problem and I wonder if someone knows a library that does that. I wasn't able to find one unfortunately.

Comment: What is stopping you from writing one?

Comment: Your 'any string' requirement is something special. There a algorithms to convert between kebap case, screaming case, camel case and whatever, but all expect that the input follows some conventions. You probably have to code it yourself...

Comment: What should the class name be for the string `"@#$*"`? And do you want to follow any convention about acronyms based on length, like XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you write one on your own?

1. split the string on every special character
2. make every first character upper case
3. concat

Comment: Sure. That is not hard to do, but I'd rather use a library that takes care about it.

Comment: Well, the question is off-topic if you are just asking us to find or recommend a library.